# R: making a list of unique values usable in Shiny selectInput

Tags: r, list, dataframe, unique, shiny

I'm working on a small Shiny App that will provide access to some publicly available labour market data. I've a relatively simple data set in a long format that resembles the extract below:

**data**

```
Geography Measure    Time  Value
ABC       Measure A  2010  3
ABC       Measure A  2011  4
ABC       Measure A  2013  5
ABC       Measure B  2010  0.2
ABC       Measure B  2011  4
DEF       Measure A  2010  4
DEF       Measure A  2011  8
DEF       Measure A  2012  7
DEF       Measure B  2010  8
DEF       Measure B  2010  7
```

I'm intending to generate a simple chart and I would like to use the `selectInput` method to provide end-users with a convenient way of filtering the tables and the corresponding data. Consequently, I would like for the `selectInput` to contain a list of unique values derived from columns against which I'm intending to apply filters. On the example of the **Measure** column I'm getting a list of unique values using the code below:

```
## Create list of unique measures
lst.measures <- as.list(unique(dta$Measure))
```

but when I attempt to introduce the obtained list to the Shiny `ui.R` using the code below:

```
  # Selection of the available indicators
  selectInput("selectVariable", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = lst.measures, 
              selected = 1)
),
```

The generated list does not contain the desired text *(Measure A, Measure B)* but a list of numbers, like in the picture below (I've more measure in my data than in the sample data):
[image: Sample List]

I'm guessing that the problem is concerned with how the list is structured, presently

```
> as.list(unique(dta.nom$Measure))
[[1]]
[1] Measure A
Levels: Measure A Measure B

[[2]]
[1] Measure B
Levels: Measure A Measure B
```

Consequently, my question is: *How can I reorder the elements within the list, so the generated list can be passed to the `selectInput` in a meaningful manner, showing the text values corresponding to the unique values of the chosen column?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try converting `dta.nom$Measure`to `character`

```
dta.nom$Measure = as.character(dta.nom$Measure)
```

Further from the top of my head I am not sure that you actually are required to pass a list to selectInput.

```
# Create list of unique measures
#lst.measures <- as.list(unique(dta$Measure))
lst.measures <- unique(dta$Measure)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the suggested solution works as it should. Can I take the opportunity and clarify with you what values are now passed from the `selectInput`? As outlined on the [Shiny website] (http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html), the `selectInput` follows structure `selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
            c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
              "Transmission" = "am"))` with the `cyl` and `am` values being passed as selected, what will be passed if I'm providing only the single list of values?

Comment: Sure you can. The notation ` c("Cylinders" = "cyl", "Transmission" = "am")` makes the options of selectInput appear as "Cylinders" and "Transmission" to the user. Internally the choices the user makes are translated as "cyl" and "am". What is important is of course the internal values. If you are ok with the user seeing variable names rather than labels there is no backside to providing only a single vector.